# Removing conditions on patterns from LHS of a rule

Tags: pattern-matching, hold, rule

Let's consider a rule which takes conditions on the patterns specified on the LHS:

```
In[1]:= rule = j[n1_?NonPositive,n2_?Positive,n3_?Positive]:>AAA
```

I would like to remove the `Positive` condition from the second and third positions, but keep the `NonPositive` condition in the first one. By looking at `FullForm[rule]`, I found one way to do it:

```
In[2]:= rule /. PatternTest:>List /. Positive->Nothing /. List[x_,y_]:>PatternTest[x,y] /. List[x_]:>x
Out[2]= j[n1_?NonPositive,n2_,n3_]:>AAA
```

but this is not very elegant. Is there a better way? I tried experimenting with `HoldPattern`, but did not manage to do it.

```
In[3]:= rule /. HoldPattern[PatternTest[x__,Positive]]:>x
Out[3]= j[n1_?NonPositive,n2_?Positive,n3_?Positive]:>AAA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rule /. Verbatim[PatternTest][x_ , Positive] :> x
```

> ```
> j[n1_?NonPositive, n2_, n3_] :> AAA
> ```

Also

```
rule /. (p:PatternTest)[x_, Positive] :> x
```

> ```
> j[n1_?NonPositive, n2_, n3_] :> AAA
> ```

and

```
 rule /. _[a_, Positive] :> a
```

> ```
> j[n1_?NonPositive, n2_, n3_] :> AAA
> ```